# Unable to access table from alias name of column

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, jboss, sybase

Select name as id, code from the employee, The query is working perfectly on my database  but when in spring boot I try to get the data from the table like:

```
Map namedQuery = (Map)iter.next();
namedQueryId = (String)namedQuery.get("namedQueryId");
for (iterator = rows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
    Map row = (Map)iterator.next();
    Object code = row.get("code");
    Object id = row.get("id");  
}
```

id is always NULL in this while getting proper data in "code".
the name is being called using alias id so it is getting null values always

Comment: You are not showing all the relevant code. While you indicate that the `SELECT name AS id, code FROM employee` is working, it appears from the little code you show that in your application, you are trying to retrieve the `id` column rather than the `name` column. Try replacing `Object id = row.get("id");` with `Object id = row.get("name");` to see if you still get `NULL`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the content of the actual query string

Comment: You can also try square brackets, if this is IQ, like row.get("[id]")